# Running Sample Java with JDBC connection and Grid DB (Fixed Mode Network configuration)

Tags: griddb

My GridDB cluster make use of Fixed Mode instead of Multicast mode. Having been able to resolve in past Java program using the notificationMember configuration to set my network address and port, I'm stuck trying to make use of same configuration to set up JDBC connection URL.

The current snippet of my JDBC java file:

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;

public class JDBCSelect {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            //===============================================
            // Connecting to a cluster
            //===============================================
            // Connection information of JDBC
            String jdbcAddress = "127.0.0.1";
            String jdbcPort = "10001";
            String clusterName = "myCluster";
            String databaseName = "public";
            String username = "admin";
            String password = "admin";
            String applicationName = "SampleJDBC";

            // Encoding a cluster name and a database name
            String encodeClusterName = URLEncoder.encode(clusterName, "UTF-8");
            String encodeDatabaseName = URLEncoder.encode(databaseName, "UTF-8");

            // Creating a URL (Multicast method)
            String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:gs://"+jdbcAddress+":"+jdbcPort+"/"+encodeClusterName+"/"+encodeDatabaseName;

            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.setProperty("user", username);
            prop.setProperty("password", password);
            prop.setProperty("applicationName", applicationName);

            // Connecting
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, prop);

            //===============================================
            // Creating a container and registering data
            //===============================================
            {
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

                // (Delete the container if it already exists)
                stmt.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SampleJDBC_Select");

                // Creating a container
                stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SampleJDBC_Select ( id integer PRIMARY KEY, value string )");
                System.out.println("SQL Create Table name=SampleJDBC_Select");

                // Registering a row
                int ret1 = stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO SampleJDBC_Select values "+
                                            "(0, 'test0'),(1, 'test1'),(2, 'test2'),(3, 'test3'),(4, 'test4')");
                System.out.println("SQL Insert count=" + ret1);

                stmt.close();
            }

            //===============================================
            // Executing a search
            //===============================================
            // (1) Creating a statement
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            // (2) Executing a SQL command
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from SampleJDBC_Select where ID > 2");

            // (3) Getting a result
            while( rs.next() ){
                int id = rs.getInt(1);
                String value = rs.getString(2);
                System.out.println("SQL row(id=" + id + ", value=" + value + ")");
            }

            //===============================================
            // Terminating process
            //===============================================
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
            System.out.println("success!");

        } catch ( Exception e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The following are the command ran on my environment:

```
export CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:/usr/share/java/gridstore-jdbc.jar:.
javac JDBCSelect.java 
java JDBCSelect
```

I got the following errors:

> [10054:TXN_CLIENT_VERSION_NOT_ACCEPTABLE] (connectClientVersion=-9, serverVersion=15) (address=127.0.0.1:10001, partitionId=0)
> at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.internal.SQLErrorUtils.error(SQLErrorUtils.java:262)
> at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.internal.SQLStatement.execute(SQLStatement.java:751)
> at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.internal.SQLConnection.(SQLConnection.java:309)
> at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.internal.SQLDriver.connect(SQLDriver.java:61)
> at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.internal.common.DriverProvider$ChainDriver.connect(DriverProvider.java:62)
> at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
> at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)
> at JDBCSelect.main(JDBCSelect.java:37)
> Caused by: com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.internal.GSStatementException: [10054:TXN_CLIENT_VERSION_NOT_ACCEPTABLE] (connectClientVersion=-9, serverVersion=15) (address=127.0.0.1:10001, partitionId=0)
> at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.internal.NodeConnection.executeStatementDirect(NodeConnection.java:574)
> at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.internal.NodeConnection.executeStatement(NodeConnection.java:381)
> at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.internal.NodeConnection.connect(NodeConnection.java:1010)
> at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.internal.NodeConnectionPool.resolve(NodeConnectionPool.java:162)
> at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.internal.NodeResolver.updateConnectionAndClusterInfo(NodeResolver.java:664)
> at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.internal.NodeResolver.prepareConnectionAndClusterInfo(NodeResolver.java:549)
> at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.internal.NodeResolver.getPartitionCount(NodeResolver.java:225)
> at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.internal.SQLConnection.getNextAddress(SQLConnection.java:1325)
> at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.internal.SQLConnection.reset(SQLConnection.java:1379)
> at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.internal.SQLStatement.execute(SQLStatement.java:564)
> ... 6 more

I will appreciate any help in resolving Fixed Mode network connection with JDBC for GridDB.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL port for GridDB is not 10001, but actually 20001. So change

String jdbcPort = "10001";

to

String jdbcPort = "20001";

Another issue I see is from the error you're reporting.

> [10054:TXN_CLIENT_VERSION_NOT_ACCEPTABLE] (connectClientVersion=-9, serverVersion=15) (address=127.0.0.1:10001, partitionId=0) at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.internal.SQLErrorUtils.error(SQLErrorUtils.java:262) at

Can you share more about your environment details, such as GridDB version, and the version of the JDBC Jar you are using? Ideally you should be using the latest for both (v5.3 I believe)

Comment: I did tried to change the port to 20001 and got this new error;
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:gs://127.0.0.1:20001/myCluster/public
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)
        at JDBCSelect.main(JDBCSelect.java:37)

Comment: I'm currently using GridDB version 5.3.0 build 39942 Community Edition and the version JDBC. I don't know how to check for the version of JDBC jar. I make use of java and javac 11.0.21

Comment: did you install GridDB by using apt or yum? or did you install the GridDB CLI? Installing the GridDB CLI package or installing the griddb-meta package through apt or yum installs the JDBC package for you. if you didn't do that, you need to manually install the JDBC jar file and add it to your path

Comment: I have been able to resolve this now. I realized running on the default user account rather than the gsadm fix this issue. Thanks so much Connell.